# Property 'name' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' - React + TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

This is my code:

```
<Button
  disabled={filter === 'Active'}
  size='md'
  color='primary'
  name='Active' // complete = false
  onClick={this.handleFilterClick}
>
  Active
</Button>
```

On my function handler I get error on the event:

```
handleFilterClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    // continue here
     const { name } = e.target;
```

It says:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
```

I also tried:

```
(e:  React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement, MouseEvent> &  React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>)
```

What is the event type for button? In JavaScript, this works, it can accept name but I don't know why not typescript?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`event.target` is the element from which element is dispatched, which necessarily doesn't have to be the `HTMLButtonElement` defined in the event.

However, if you use `event.currentTarget`, you will see that this error goes away:

```
const { name } = event.currentTarget;
```

If you have to use `event.target` itself, you would have to cast the object:

```
const { name } = event.target as HTMLButtonElement;
```

From the typings:

```
/**
  * currentTarget - a reference to the element on which the event listener is registered.
  *
  * target - a reference to the element from which the event was originally dispatched.
  * This might be a child element to the element on which the event listener is registered.
  * If you thought this should be `EventTarget & T`, see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/12239
*/
```

Comment: Agree with using currentTarget. You could also refine event.target rather than casting. `if (e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement) { e.target.name; }`

Comment: @TLadd true, that would be the better way

Answer (score 0):

While the solution proposed by @Agney will probably work in most cases, it failed me when I was using event delegation – the property I want to access was on the child element, which was `event.target`, not `event.currentTarget`.

I appease the TS compiler with broadening the type of `event.target`:

```
const handleMouseMove = (e: React.MouseEvent<SVGSVGElement>) => {
  // Hey, compiler, the event target can have any of the properties of an SVG element:
  const target: EventTarget & React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> = e.target
  if (target.id) {
    // ...
  }
```

The example is using `id` property instead of `name`, but the principle is the same. The compiler error is gone.