# random word replacement using react from js code

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to lean react by solving a js problem in react. Providing the js code challenge below. I am seeing the below error in editor and I am not seeing any error in browser console. I googled but still no luck, not sure how to solve it. Providing my code below and stackblitz. Can you guys help me.

Error: Property 'dataset' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.(2339)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-d3neo5?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fstyle.css,src%2Findex.tsx&title=React%20Starter

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xd08ZrFCiJ4&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9hhNl8shRf6TIL-dNkpSRV0&index=10

```
import { FC } from 'react';

import './style.css';

export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
  const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
  const output = document.querySelector('.output');

  // flavours
  const flavours = {
    ninja: ['dojo', 'shogun', 'shinobi', 'samuri', 'shuriken'],
    pokemon: ['pika', 'pokeball', 'pokedex', 'evolve', 'ash', 'gym'],
    space: ['universe', 'galaxy', 'telescope', 'comet', 'stars'],
  };

  // functions
  const flavourize = (inputText, flavour) => {
    const textArray = inputText.split(' ');

    for (let i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
      if (i % 3 === 0) {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * flavour.length);
        textArray[i] = flavour[random];
      }
    }

    return textArray.join(' ');
  };

  const updateOutput = (text) => {
    output.textContent = text;
  };

  // event listener
  buttons.forEach((b) => {
    b.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (textarea.value) {
        const f = e.target.dataset.flavour;
        const text = flavourize(textarea.value, flavours[f]);
        updateOutput(text);
      }
    });
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>

      <form>
        <textarea></textarea>
        <div className="buttons">
          <p>Choose your theme:</p>
          <button data-flavour="ninja">Ninja</button>
          <button data-flavour="pokemon">Pokemon</button>
          <button data-flavour="space">Space</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```js
const f = e.target.dataset.flavour;
```

with

```js
const f = (e.target as HTMLButtonElement).dataset.flavour;
```

as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55389447/9997212).

TypeScript is a stricter language than JavaScript in terms of typing, so you must cast `e.target` before accessing its `dataset` attribute.

Comment: thanks for your response I updated my code but still random text functionality not working can you update in my stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-d3neo5?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fstyle.css,src%2Findex.tsx&title=React%20Starter